# Expressing Interest for Waitlists on more than 1 program (Ph.D Admissions in STEM)

Tags: graduate-admissions

This is for Ph.D admissions in STEM area.

I was put on the waitlist for >5 schools where I have applied to, some of which have emailed me asking if I am still interested for consideration of their "second round of offers."

The dilemma is, what if I expressed interest to (say) >3 schools that I am still interested, but at the end I ended up with >1 offer from them? Doesn't that make me a liar since I have to (due to pigeonhole's) decline at least 1 offer?

Don't get me wrong. I'm more than willing to attend any of the schools where I'm currently on the waitlist, I'm just worried it will put me in an awkward position.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

(posting anonymously, since some of the contributors here are graduate directors of programs I applied to)

Answer (score 3):

They are using this question to find out if you have already accepted another offer.

If you say you are interested, what you would be implying is that if this is the only additional offer you get, you would seriously consider attending. There is nothing wrong with being interested in more than one program.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

> what if I expressed interest to (say) >3 schools that I am still interested, but at the end I ended up with >1 offer from them? Doesn't that make me a liar

No it does not.  Say you are interested if that is true.  If you are so lucky as to get multiple offers, accept one and politely decline the others.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I feel better now.